# ImageView in ScrollView is resized wrong

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I am using a ImageView, to be exactly it is an ImageMap extending an ImageView, in a ScrollView with the following part of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ctc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/de.svennergr.htn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/login_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3333"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Login:" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/password_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3333"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Password:" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/email_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3333"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="E-Mail:"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/login_edit"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3333"
                    android:ems="10" >
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwd_edit"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3333"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email_edit"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3333"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@color/button_start" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/register"
            android:textColor="@color/button_start" />

        <de.svennergr.htn.ImageMap
            android:id="@+id/imap"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/europa"
            ctc:map="europa" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've posted the whole XML-Code to get you a better overview.

The Imageview should display the Image with "fill_parent" to the bottom of the display, but the image is beeing resized and is not beeing displayed to the bottom:

[image: Image with the resized ImageView]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this property to your scrollview:

```
android:FillViewport="true"
```

Edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked with "android:fillViewport="true"".

Comment: I will. But I still having some complications. When I put the ImageView before the 2 buttons, the buttons aren't displayed anymore. Any suggestion?

Comment: And in addition: I can scroll the scrollview, when I focus an EditText, but when I don't focus anything, I cant scroll it.